# x86 - Assembly, sub and imul doesn't work

Tags: assembly, x86

The program count result subtraction or multiplication depending on the specified the last argument (example: "./a.out 2 4 -" = -2; "./a.out 5 8 x" = 40). The program doesn't print anything on the screen if the last argument is '-' or 'x'. Why???

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.text
.globl _start

_start:
  mov edx, 0
  mov ecx, [esp+16]
  cmp byte ptr [ecx], 45
  jz only_min
  cmp byte ptr [ecx], 120
  jz only_mul

wrong:
  mov edx, 20
  mov ecx, offset wrong_msg
  jmp final

only_min:
  cmp byte ptr [ecx+1], 0
  jz min
  jmp wrong

only_mul:
  cmp byte ptr [ecx+1], 0
  jz mul
  jmp wrong

loop:
  inc edx
  cmp byte ptr [ecx+edx-1], 0
  jnz loop
  jmp final

min:
  mov ecx, dword ptr [esp+8]
  sub ecx, dword ptr [esp+12]
  mov edx, 4
  jmp final

mul:
  mov ecx, dword ptr [esp+8]
  imul ecx, dword ptr [esp+12]
  mov edx, 4
  jmp final

final:
  mov ebx, 1
  mov eax, 4
  int 0x80
  mov edx, 1
  mov ecx, offset newline
  mov ebx, 1
  mov eax, 4
  int 0x80
  mov ebx, 0
  mov eax, 1
  int 0x80

.data
wrong_msg:
  .asciz "Wrong last argument!"

newline:
  .asciz "\n"
```

Comment: It probably does print the result but not in ASCII. Did you do the proper ASCII-numeric and numeric-ASCII conversions?

Comment: Try `./a.out b ! -`. If it displays uppercase A then it is indeed what I suspect

Comment: Without reading into your question, I can assure you both SUB and IMUL **does work correctly**, just like the CPU was designed and their functionality described in Intel reference guide. The problem is 99.9999999% on your side.

Comment: What do you mean about these conversions?

Comment: "./a.out b ! -" show "Segfaulted"

Answer (score 2):

Now I did check your source too, and it doesn't do anything meaningful. You don't understand the format of arguments you receive, and you don't understand the format of arguments for `int 80h, 4` (sys_write).

```
mov ecx, dword ptr [esp+8]
```

loads pointer to an `<OS encoding>` string (probably UTF-8, so you can treat it as ASCII, as long as digits are involved).

If you did enter `./a.out 12 23456 -`, then `ecx` will point to first byte of string `31 32 00` (hexa bytes forming nul terminated `"12"`) and `dword ptr [esp+12]` is address of string consisting of bytes `32 33 34 35 36 00`.

So you are SUB/IMUL-ing two addresses.

Then for `sys_write` you should give file handler in `ebx` (1 == stdout, so correct in your code), `edx` is length of buffer to write, and `ecx` is address of buffer.

If you want to produce output like "-23444", you must prepare somewhere in memory ASCII bytes (hexa) `2D 32 33 34 34 34`, and load the `ecx` with address to the first byte `2D` (`'-'` or 45 in decimal), and `edx` with `6`, to display such string.

Maybe you may want to play first with strings to not have to do string->number and number->string conversions? Or link against clib, so you can call `printf/scanf` family of functions to process those arguments and prepare output.

(there are no service calls working with "numbers" in `int 80h`, only buffers of bytes are supported (you can think about them as sort of "strings", although it's not accurate).

Comment: Ok, after a long time I solved the problem. If anyone is interested solution enough to write a comment.

Comment: @tadamczyk just a ~week... if you fully understand my answer *now*, plus your solution, then that's not bad, seems OK to me. If you just managed to glue together some samples of instructions which somehow do what you expect, without really understanding how, then you have still some work to do. :) GL.